# I want to store time as a hrs:min:sec Format in database and also display time as it is hrs:min:sec format

Tags: php, mysql, time

I use time datatype for save time in db(mysql).
When I store time in db then save in 00:05:00.000000 format but I want to store only hrs:min:sec(00:05:00) in db.

Also display hrs:min:sec(00:05:00) on my front-view.

Comment: So truncate it before saving.

Comment: for me the best way to store datetime is timestamp, later you can format datetime in anything you want, and its faster

Comment: exactly @Zeljka wrote, format it before displaying, dont reinvent bicycle

Comment: do the maths before saving it to table

Comment: You don't store a format, you store a time, you format it when you display it.

Answer (score -1):

$newtime = date("H:i:s", strtotime($this->time));
try it like this